# Android Studio Material design menu inflation

Tags: android-studio, menu, material-design

I am trying to inflate a menu when selecting items from the list for multiple deletion, but instead I get a new menu bar on top of the current one.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJMLR.jpg

I used the default navigation drawer activity and then made my fragments.
I am using listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener this is my code

Java Code:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.delete, menu);
            return true;
        }
```

XML Code in menu:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/delete_id"
                android:title="Delete"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_delete"/>
        </menu>
```

The Java code happens in on onResume() in one of my fragments.
I am a beginner so please be kind thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, just add these two lines in your stlyes

```
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```